# Vue.js unit test - mock service with async data

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

Project: https://github.com/marioedgar/webpack-unit-test

I have a Vue.js app I generated with the vue CLI. I've only edited the HelloWorld component slightly to fetch some async data from my test service, you can see that here:

```js
<template>
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  import service from './test.service'
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    created () {
      service.getMessage().then(message => {
        this.message = message
      })
    },
    data () {
      return {
        message: 'A'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

The test service lives in the same directory and is very simple:

```js
class Service {
  getMessage () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('hello from test service')
      resolve('B')
    })
  }
}

const service = new Service()
export default service
```

So in order to mock this service, im using the webpack vue-loader to inject the mock service as described in the official documentation here:

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/testing-with-mocks.html

So here is my test which is almost identical to the example:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
const HelloInjector = require('!!vue-loader?inject!../../../src/components/HelloWorld')

const Hello = HelloInjector({
  // mock it
  './test.service': {
    getMessage () {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('C')
      })
    }
  }
})

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const vm = new Vue({
      template: '<div><test></test></div>',
      components: {
        'test': Hello
      }
    }).$mount()
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('h1').textContent).to.equal('C')
  })
})
```

There are two issues i am facing:

1. The test fails because the assertion is executing before the mocked promise is resolved. From my understanding, this is because the vue lifecycle hasnt completely finished when im doing my asserting. The common patter to wait for the next cycle would be to wrapp my assertion around the next tick function like this:

```js
  it('should render', (done) => {
    const vm = new Vue({
      template: '<div><test></test></div>',
      components: {
        'test': Hello
      }
    }).$mount()
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      expect(vm.$el.querySelector('h1').textContent).to.equal('C')
      done()
    })
  })
```

This, however, does not work unless I nest 3 nextTicks, which seems extremely hacky to me. Is there something I am missing to get this to work? this example seems extremely straightforward, but I cannot get this test to pass without lots of nextTicks

1. I keep getting a strange error, intermittently... this warning shows up probably 50% of the time and is not consistant at all.

[vue warn] Failed to mount component: template or render function is not defined

Again, this happens only sometimes. I can run the same exact unit test without any changes and it will show me this message 50% of the time.

Comment: Here is the link to my public repo:

https://github.com/marioedgar/webpack-unit-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I truly couldn't figure out why sometimes the component failed to mount. I'm not even sure it's related to the injector but, in any case, I kept the test consistent by not using it; trying a different approach instead.

The component might be more testable if the service is injected through the `props` instead of being directly used.

```html
<template>
  <div>
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  import service from './test.service'

  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    created () {
      this.service.getMessage().then(message => {
        this.message = message
      })
    },
    data () {
      return {
        message: 'A'
      }
    },
    props: {
      service: {
        default: service
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

This makes the injector unnecessary as the mocked service can be instead passed to the component using `propsData` in the constructor.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

import Async from '@/components/Async'

const service = {
  getMessage () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve('C')
    })
  }
}

describe('Async.vue', () => {
  let vm
  before(() => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(Async)
    vm = new Constructor({
      propsData: {
        service: service
      }
    }).$mount()
  })
  it('should render', function () {
    // Wrapping the tick inside a promise, bypassing PhantomJS's lack of support
    return (new Promise(resolve => Vue.nextTick(() => resolve()))).then(() => {
      expect(vm.$el.querySelector('h1').textContent).to.equal('C')
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I do like this better than using the injector, this does fix one of the issues i was facing. Its unfortunate that the extra ticks are neccessary. Im wondering if can do that in a before() to avoid all this extra code in each test. That or i can add a simple async helper function.

Comment: You are correct. Using mocha's `before` the tests only enter until the component if fully mounted, so only one tick is necessary. I changed the code to reflect this.